# Is Javascript code being processed after clicking on a submit button?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, form-submit

I am working on a ECommerce Project. During the checkout process there is the button to purchase the item at the end of the checkout process. Clicking on that button submits the form on the page using a POST request (Standard, no AJAX). However, if you click on that submit button multiple times really quick, multiple POST Requests are sent to the server and so there are also multiple Orders being created.

My Question: Is it save to prevent these multiple button clicks by javascript, or is the page in a weird state at some point because the new page load kicks in?

Is there a difference about that if I do it with inline script:

```
onsubmit="if(submitted) return false; submitted = true; return true"
```

Or in my JS external file?

Another option would be to disable the submit button right after the form submit, but IE adds really Ugly Font Color to the button, which cannot be removed by CSS.

Comment: You can abort AJAX requests. If you're debating inline or external, _always_ external, writing JavaScript as a string is antipattern.

Comment: But the Request is NOT an Ajax Request..So it is a standard Page Load with e Form POST Submit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page continues to process events and run javascript until the form Post returns new content which then replaces the current document, thus loading a new document.  It is not in a weird state and works normally until the new content arrives and the current document is closed.

There are various techniques for preventing multiple presses of the button.  Your code can keep track of the fact that a post has already been sent (in a global variable) and block any more being sent whenever that variable is set.  In the UI, you can disable the button as soon as the first post is initiated so the button can't be pressed again.

Comment: Ah ok, thats cool..so I will do it with a JS Variable Status, which knows, if the form was already submitted.. Thanks for that information